# Is there any flag in spinner to specify that text can be in more than one line?

Tags: android, android-widget

I have spinner on screen and when I click I get choices ( default behavior of spinner ). Problem is that in some items text is to long so it is cropped. Is there any flag in spinner to specify that text can be in more than one line ? How to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 1):

Change the layout that you pass to the adapter:

```
final SimpleCursorAdapter quartierAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
                YourActivity.this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, // the layout to change
                curseurInitialQuartier,
                new String[] { DBhelper.KEY_NOM },
                new int[] { android.R.id.text1 });
```

Make your own layout and put it there.

Answer (score 0):

a very common issue . possible  solution are :

1) set text size in sp .
2) create flexible layout , which can very along with text length .
3) in case 2 is not feasible , fix textView length and crop remaining portion, i guess no trick will be possible .